# Compare contents of two pages

Tags: javascript, css, dom, diff

A question about existing tools.

Background: 
I have a system where we uses versioning a lot. To compare versions we now dumps the information to a text-format and then print the two versions of the text with colored markings. I doesn't look nice and is quite hard for the users to understand.

I'd like to improve on this and actually show the two versions web-pages redered markup and then use some kind of css-markers to show where there are differences between the two pages. What I imagine to be the problem with this kind of apporach is that there are a lot of objects in the dom that doesn't directly affect the rendering and therefore would need to be filtered away for the diff to make sence.

Question:
Is there any existing tools that would allow me to compare the doms of to pages and then render apply some kind of visual clues to what is added, changed or removed? It needs to run in the browser only.
Is it a viable approch at all?

Comment: I've seen may approaches using images and png/screen shots, but not rendering the saved dom from two pages. is there a reason why two screenshots with differences hightlighted wouldnt be sufficient?

Comment: @atmd How to get the highlights on the screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by taking screenshots (automatically) of the 2 dom structure and comparing those images. that way you are not saving/rendering the dom. you can even use a headless browser like node to do it for you, making it quick and easily integrated into your automated testing.

There are several tools to help you do this rather then writing your own from scratch, such as [resemble.js](https://github.com/Huddle/Resemble.js). (however if you prefer you can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) to write it yourself using their api's.

These tools allow you to highlight the differences in two images [image]

there is also a good article [here on automated-screenshot-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/automated-screenshot-diff) which is another node package that can compare two screenshot of dom renderings.